# How to make the entire column scrollable when there is a mixed of PageView, ListView and GridView?

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I'd like to make the entire column scrollable together with PageView, ListView and GridView. At the moment, the 3 widgets scroll individually. The PageView and ListView scroll horizontally and i'd like to keep that. The GridView.build scrolls vertically and i don't want it to scroll by itself, instead i want the whole 3 widgets to scroll together, vertically.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:smooth_page_indicator/smooth_page_indicator.dart';
import 'listing.dart';


class TrackPage extends StatelessWidget {

  final _controller = PageController(
    initialPage: 0
  );

  TrackPage({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 224, 174, 113),
      appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      elevation: 0,
      leading: BackButton(
        color: Colors.black,
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
      centerTitle: true,
      title: Text('Vouchers', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
    ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
         Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 20),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 200,
              child: Expanded(
                child: PageView(
                  controller: _controller,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 20,
                      color: Color(0xFFE2D240),
                      child: 
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          Image.asset('lib/images/x.png', width: 150,), 
                          Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Center(child: Text('35% Off')),
                              SizedBox(height: 20),
                              Text('Super Cool')
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      )),
                    Container(
                      height: 20,
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: 
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          Image.asset('lib/images/x.png', width: 150,), 
                          Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Center(child: Text('30% Off')),
                              SizedBox(height: 20),
                              Text('Super Cool')
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      )),
                    Container(
                      height: 20,
                      color: Colors.green,
                      child: 
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          Image.asset('lib/images/x.png', width: 150,), 
                          Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Center(child: Text('25% Off')),
                              SizedBox(height: 20),
                              Text('Super Cool')
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      )),
                  ]
                 ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SmoothPageIndicator(
            controller: _controller, count: 3,
            effect: WormEffect(
              dotColor: Colors.blueGrey,
              activeDotColor: Colors.blue,
              dotWidth: 8,
              dotHeight: 8,
            ),),
      
         SizedBox(
          height: 20,
         ),
         //Tags in list view
        SizedBox(
          height: 50,
          child: ListView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            children: [
          Listing(text: 'Test',),
          Listing(text: 'Test',),
          Listing(text: 'Test',),
          Listing(text: 'Test',
            onTap: null,),
          Listing(text: 'Test',),
          Listing(text: 'Test',),
          ]
          ),
          ),
      
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: GridView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            itemCount: 6,
           gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            mainAxisSpacing: 15,
            crossAxisSpacing: 15,
            ),
           itemBuilder: (context, index){
            return Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
              height: 20,
              width: 20,
              color: Colors.white,
            );
           }),
        ),
        //Gallery pictures in grid view
        Image.asset('lib/images/x.png', width: 20,),
        ],
      ),

      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: 0,
        items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Test'),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Test'),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Test'),
        ]
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Like below, i've tried to stop the GridView.builder from scrolling by applying the NeverScrollableScrollPhysics and apply the SingleChildScrollView to the Column, but that seems to cause some issue as everything is missing in the screen. I also tried to wrap the SingleChildScrollView using an Expanded widget, but same issue remains.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:smooth_page_indicator/smooth_page_indicator.dart';
import 'listing.dart';


class TrackPage extends StatelessWidget {

  final _controller = PageController(
    initialPage: 0
  );

  TrackPage({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 224, 174, 113),
      appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      elevation: 0,
      leading: BackButton(
        color: Colors.black,
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
      centerTitle: true,
      title: Text('Vouchers', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
    ),
      body: Expanded(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
             Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 20),
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 200,
                  child: Expanded(
                    child: PageView(
                      controller: _controller,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          height: 20,
                          color: Color(0xFFE2D240),
                          child: 
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: [
                              Image.asset('lib/images/x.png', width: 150,), 
                              Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  Center(child: Text('35% Off')),
                                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                                  Text('Super Cool')
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          )),
                        Container(
                          height: 20,
                          color: Colors.red,
                          child: 
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: [
                              Image.asset('lib/images/x.png', width: 150,), 
                              Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  Center(child: Text('30% Off')),
                                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                                  Text('Super Cool')
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          )),
                        Container(
                          height: 20,
                          color: Colors.green,
                          child: 
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: [
                              Image.asset('lib/images/x.png', width: 150,), 
                              Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  Center(child: Text('25% Off')),
                                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                                  Text('Super Cool')
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          )),
                        
                      ]
                     ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
          
              SmoothPageIndicator(
                controller: _controller, count: 3,
                effect: WormEffect(
                  dotColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                  activeDotColor: Colors.blue,
                  dotWidth: 8,
                  dotHeight: 8,
                ),),
          
             SizedBox(
              height: 20,
             ),
             //Tags in list view
            SizedBox(
              height: 50,
              child: ListView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                children: [
              Listing(text: 'Test',),
              Listing(text: 'Test',),
              Listing(text: 'Test',),
              Listing(text: 'Test',
                onTap: null,),
              Listing(text: 'Test',),
              Listing(text: 'Test',),
              ]
              ),
              ),
          
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
          
            Expanded(
              child: GridView.builder(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                itemCount: 6,
               gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                mainAxisSpacing: 15,
                crossAxisSpacing: 15,
                ),
               itemBuilder: (context, index){
                return Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
                  height: 20,
                  width: 20,
                  color: Colors.white,
                );
               }),
            ),
          
            //Gallery pictures in grid view
            Image.asset('lib/images/x.png', width: 20,),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),

      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: 0,
        items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Test'),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Test'),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Test'),
        ]
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are wrapping Column widget with SingleChildScrollView, it's children should have specific size. So either give the childern specific size of wrap with Expanded widget. (I had similar issue, but I did'nt implement all the scrollables under Column.)

Comment: I wrapped PageView, ListView and GridView around a SizedBoxed and Expanded, i then added the SingleSchildScrollView like i showed. Same issue, no screen showing after doing that.

Comment: Actually now I tried to recreate the same, and replaced Expanded widgets with container and gave specific height and width. Then also same blank screen. So I changed SingleChildScrollView(child: Column())   with  ListView. Now everything is visible.(but very messy, so give proper height and widgth)

Comment: Would you mind sharing your code? as i've tried, but could not replicate the same result.